# Importing .js disables jQuery Mobile CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

According to convention, I'm importing an initializing JavaScript file into my jQuery Mobile pages

init.js

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.fallbackTransition.slideout = "none"
});
```

page.html

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="init.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

For some reason, this removes all the styles from the jQuery Mobile CSS?

Comment: The snippet for "init.js" is currently missing `);` from the end for the call to `.bind()`. Is this just a typo in the question or is it also missing from the file?

Comment: What is the full code in the `init.js` file?

Comment: Sorry, I added it. But I was expecting the problem in page.html (see Vinay's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jquery mobile js and css files must be added in proper order.This might be the problem in your case.hope the below example helps.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks the reordering fixed it, I don't know why I never tried to change it a bit in the first place. I got it from the jQuery Mobile docs(which means it has the order wrong there..): http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html